# How to assign value individually in VBA to prevent "Can't Assign To Array"?

Tags: excel, vba, iteration

When i execute below function, i am getting "Can't assign to array" compile error.

I try to change x2() to x2 and get : "Subscript out of range" for any length i used or Mismatch error.

```
Public Function Residual(x1() As Variant, x2() As Variant)
    Dim temp1() As Variant, temp2 As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, le As Integer
    le = UBound(x1) - LBound(x1)
    For i = 1 To le
        temp1(i) = x2 - x1(i)
        temp2 = temp2 + temp1(i)
    Next i
    Residual = temp2 / le
End Function

Public Function Jacobi(A() As Variant, b() As Variant, x() As Variant, err As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, le As Integer
    le = UBound(A) - LBound(A)
    ReDim Dia(1 To le, 1 To le)
    ReDim Low(1 To le, 1 To le)
    ReDim Upp(1 To le, 1 To le)

    For i = 1 To le
        For j = 1 To le
            If i = j Then
            Dia(i, j) = A(i, j)
            Else: Dia(i, j) = 0
            End If
        Next j
        For j = i + 1 To le
            If i < j Then
            Low(i, j) = A(i, j)
            Else: Low(i, j) = 0
            End If
        Next j
        For j = i + 1 To le
            If i > j Then
            Upp(i, j) = A(i, j)
            Else: Upp(i, j) = 0
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Dim temp1() As Variant, temp2() As Variant, temp3() As Variant, x1() As Variant, x2() As Variant

    x1 = x
    Do While Residual(x1, x2) > err
        temp1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(Application.WorksheetFunction.MInverse(Dia), Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Low, Upp))
        temp2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(temp1, x1)
        temp3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(Application.WorksheetFunction.MInverse(Dia), b)
        x2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(temp2, temp3)
        x1 = x2
    Loop
    Jacobi = x2
End Function
Sub cek()
    Dim A() As Variant, b() As Variant, x() As Variant
    Dim hasil As Integer

    A = Range("A1:C3")
    b = Range("D1:D3")
    x = Range("E1:E3")
    hasil = Jacobi(A, b, x, 0.0001)
End Sub
```

I'm new to VBA and this program for Jacobi method. What i did wrong?

Comment: The short identifiers and lack of proper block indentation makes the code rather hard to read/follow, so I only superficially glanced at it, but consider declaring your variant arrays `foo As Variant` instead of `foo() As Variant`. Also note that the unqualified `Range` calls in `cek` are implicitly referring to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is, and all involve an implicit `_Default` member call that you could make explicit by appending `.Value` to populate the 2D variant arrays.

Comment: That said `temp1(i) = x2 - x1(i)` is clearly trying to subtract an array from an array element, and VBA doesn't do set operations on arrays, if that's what you intended to do here. Did you mean `= x2(i) - x1(i)`?

Comment: One more thing: the `err` parameter is hiding/shadowing the `VBA.Information.Err` global function, which is fundamental for any kind of debugging and/or error-handling. You will definitely want to rename that to something else.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon Thank you for your advices, i will try to use them and post the result.